# The number of minimum dominating sets for the graphs : $P_n$ and $C_n$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What is the number of minimum dominating sets for the graphs: $P_n$ and $C_n$
I don't know where to start, though I have a couple of Ideas:

1. Using the fromula for the number of answers of $x_1+x_2+...+x_k = n$.
2. The answer may have a component of $n\choose \lceil \frac{n}{3} \rceil$ for the $P_n$ case.

Please provide a general formula to obtain the number of minimum dominating sets in

A) $P_n$ graph with labelled vertices and

B) $C_n$ graph with labelled vertices.

Comment: Start with the special cases $n=1,2,3,4,5,6$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62134/minimum-dominating-set-and-minimum-vertex-cover-proof